# ListView using BaseAdapter not showing in Activity

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm trying to inflate a list using baseadapter within an activity. The list just doesn't inflate. From the logs implemented within the class, the `getView()` function doesn't even execute. Here's the code. -

```
public class CallLog extends Activity {
    ListView logList;
    List mList;
    Context mCtx;
    ArrayList<String> logName;
    ArrayList<String> logNumber;
    ArrayList<String> logTime;
    @Override
    protected  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reject_call_log);
        mCtx = getApplicationContext();
        ListView logList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.log_list);
        mList = new List(mCtx, R.layout.log_row);
        logList.setAdapter(mList);
        SharedPreferences savedLogName = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mCtx);
        SharedPreferences savedLogNumber = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mCtx);
        SharedPreferences savedLogTime = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mCtx);
        try{
            logName = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(savedLogName.getString("logName", null), ",")));
            logNumber = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(savedLogNumber.getString("logNumber", null), ",")));
            logTime = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(TextUtils.split(savedLogTime.getString("logTime", null), ",")));
            Collections.reverse(logName);
            Collections.reverse(logNumber);
            Collections.reverse(logTime);
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            //TextView noLog = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.no_log);
        }

    }

    public class List extends BaseAdapter {
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        TextView nameText;
        TextView numberText;
        TextView timeText;
        int timePos = 1;
        public List(Context context, int resource) {
        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            }
            nameText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.log_name);
            numberText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.log_number);
            timeText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.log_time);
            nameText.setText(logName.get(position));
            numberText.setText(logNumber.get(position));
            timeText.setText(logTime.get(timePos) + logTime.get(timePos+1));
            Log.d("RejectCall", "ListView");
            timePos+=2;
            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

Where is it all going wrong? Also, is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: what do you think `public int getCount() {
            return 0;
        }` does, exactly?

Comment: Returns the count of any of the variables logName, logNumber logTime (they all hold the same number of data). I've corrected my code there with logName.size(). I'm using lists for the first time. Still a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

Please replace the following code :

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }
```

with

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return logName.size();
    }
```

**As list view only show the numbers of rows that is returned by this method and right now you are returning 0;**

And after fetching the data in arraylist please use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to notify the list view.

You have to call notifyDataSetChanged() as you are filling data in array list after setting the adapter. so to notify the list view that data has been changed you have to call notify method(as above)

Comment: But how am I returning 0 rows? The variables logName, logNumber and logTime hold data, and I want to show them in a single row. To do that, I inflate a list, and then pass in those variables with setText. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Slay, Ya you are passing all the data to adapter : but that is having two problems :
1. You are adding data to lists after setting the adapter to list view so list view is not having knowledge about data.
2. BaseAdapter overrides method getCount() internally list view call this and get how much row it has to display so we have to return the size of your array list.

Answer (score 0):

Your getItem() and getCount() haven't been implemented. If you want any kind of adapter to work for the list, these need to be implemented. Your list is also not holding any actual data, so getItem() has nothing to set.

Don't forget to call notifiyDataSetChanged() in your adapter after you set appropriate implementations for the above two functions.

Comment: Hi, could you please explain what you mean by "Your list is also not holding any actual data, so getItem() has nothing to set."?

Comment: Ah, I think I get what you meant now. the variables logName, logNumber and logTime indeed hold data. The data is received using sharedpreferences and stored in those variables.